# Crash on IOS app in testflight (delphi10.4)

Tags: ios, delphi, crash, testflight

The last days i deployed a new app to testflight. Now we have 2 different iphone's to test with.(Iphone 7plus and Iphone6). On the iphone 6 it works fine and we have no single error or crash. on the iphone 7plus when we open it on testflight it instantly crashes after showing the splashscreen. I have an crash.log but i cant unterstand it where this crash is comming from. We tested today on an iphone 8plus and there is the exact same crash. als the three devices are IOS14.3 and testflight version3. We deploying it form delphi with IphoneOS13.5. Here is the crashlog. I hope you guys can help me out with this.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d47e184c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd3d9e8 pthread_kill + 212 (pthread.c:1388)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b234d8f4 abort + 100 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bd14ecc8 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bd140bf8 demangling_terminate_handler() + 128 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:72)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bd14e154 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bd14e0fc std::terminate() + 60 (cxa_handlers.cpp:92)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a92da294 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:562)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a927f930 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224 (queue.c:468)
9   FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b8083f20 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40 (FBSSerialQueue.m:184)
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b8083be8 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 404 (FBSSerialQueue.m:227)
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b80840bc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28 (FBSSerialQueue.m:258)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a9621be0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1967)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a9621ae0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2011)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a9620e28 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256 (CFRunLoop.c:2048)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a961b3d0 __CFRunLoopRun + 776 (CFRunLoop.c:2925)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a961ab90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
17  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bf93d598 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2259)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001abf04638 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052 (UIApplication.m:3266)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001abf09bb8 UIApplicationMain + 164 (UIApplication.m:4738)
20  CWN                             0x0000000102dce38c 0x102934000 + 4825996
21  CWN                             0x0000000102e594c8 0x102934000 + 5395656
22  CWN                             0x000000010364042c 0x102934000 + 13681708
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a92f9588 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd4186c _pthread_dependency_fulfill_slow + 192 (pthread_dependency.c:57)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d47be644 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d47bda48 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CWN                             0x000000010295ca64 0x102934000 + 166500
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd3cb3c _pthread_start + 288 (pthread.c:881)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd41880 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd4186c _pthread_dependency_fulfill_slow + 192 (pthread_dependency.c:57)

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd4186c _pthread_dependency_fulfill_slow + 192 (pthread_dependency.c:57)

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd4186c _pthread_dependency_fulfill_slow + 192 (pthread_dependency.c:57)

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd4186c _pthread_dependency_fulfill_slow + 192 (pthread_dependency.c:57)

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d47be644 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d47bda48 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a96210ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a961b560 __CFRunLoopRun + 1176 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a961ab90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001aa8387f8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001aa8386d8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001abfb0438 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 504 (UIEventFetcher.m:836)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001aa9954bc __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd3cb3c _pthread_start + 288 (pthread.c:881)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001efd41880 thread_start + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001bd151f5a   x5: 0x000000016d4ca370   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000283c6dfe0
    x8: 0x0000000107353880   x9: 0x5ca3286a63b9e46d  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x0000000000000012
   x12: 0x00000001bd151f8c  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x000000000000001a
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x0000000107353960  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000107353960
   x24: 0x000000020068e000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000282454c08  x27: 0x00000002000b1000
   x28: 0x000000020068e000   fp: 0x000000016d4ca2d0   lr: 0x00000001efd3d9e8
    sp: 0x000000016d4ca2b0   pc: 0x00000001d47e184c cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

*EDIT 31-12-2020 EDIT*
I am in the right direction. There is someting wrong with the layout of the app. I made an new app and copied the layout of the crashing app and now it crashes too. if i do my own layout there is no crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error came from the webbrowser component. I think its not usable anymore.

Comment: Downvoted because the first part of the answer is vague, and the second part is wrong